# Set location simulator City/GPX during Runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

Is there a method to programmatically change the location simulator city during runtime? For example this would allow tests to simulate London or Tokyo.

The image below shows how to switch between locations (GPX files) manually. How can I achieve this result programmatically while the app is running?

[image]

Comment: Yeah, you can add a GPX File

Comment: @DiogoAntunes yes I have two GPX files added. How can I switch between them during runtime (without manually clicking the option)?

Comment: You can't :) not without manually selecting it

Comment: @DiogoAntunes Are you 100% certain? Trying to use this for development (not production).

Comment: I had the same issue on a previous project and after several hours of headbanging I found no solution. So am I 100% certain? No, but 99% ;)

Comment: @DiogoAntunes ok - I was thinking worst case maybe a script could do the job

Answer (score 1):

Alternate way to set location is by swizzling 'location' of 'CLLocationManager' class. In obj-c,

```
+(void) load {
   // replace 'location' with 'custom_location' method
 }
```

Then implement custom_location method with whatever the location you want to set by simply changing 'kMockedLatitude' and 'kMockedLongitude' variables.

```
//Portland, USA
CLLocationDegrees kMockedLatitude = 45.52306;
CLLocationDegrees kMockedLongitude = -122.67648;

-(CLLocation *)custom_location  
{  
   return [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:kMockedLatitude longitude:kMockedLongitude];
}
```

This will work even in iOS device.

Comment: Any way to accomplish this with using only GPX files? The files have complex waypoint routes and timing so overriding Cllocafion would not work.

Comment: This won't work with GPX. But it's one of the way to change location programmatically. I was doing this for one of my project.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38493642/automating-xcode-debug-simulate-location-command/38632244#38632244

Comment: @SaRaVaNaNDM Can you please guide me how I can change location on runtime? I'm using .gpx file for this purpose but I can change the location from Xcode.

Comment: @SaRaVaNaNDM I want to change location according to user entered Longitude and Latitude.